# Can I format a string in 2 times in java?

Tags: java, string, format

Imagine I have a string like this :

```java
String toFormatS = "%s, %s ; %s, %s";
```

Is there a way to formate this string with 2 consecutive `Format` like this ?

```java
if (condition1) {
     toFormatS = String.Format(toFormatS, "foo", "foo2");
// that would make toFormatS equals to "foo, foo2 ; %s, %s"
}
if (condition2) {
     toFormatS = String.Format(toFormatS, "foo3", "foo4");
// that would make toFormatS equals to "foo, foo2 ; foo3, foo4"
}
```

I'd like to do this because I have a function which returns a string with no `%s` if `!condition1`, 2 `%s` if `condition1` and 4 if `condition1 && condition2`

Here is the result using the Turo's answer :

```java
public String getFormatS(int i) {
   String r = "result : "+i;
   if (i > 15) {
     r += "1 : %s, %s";
   }
   if (i > 20) {
     r += "2 : %s, %s";
   } 
}

...
String s = getFormatS(x);
if (x > 15) {
     String.Format(s, "foo1", "foo2", "%s", "%s");
}
if (x > 20) {
     String.Format(s, "foo3", "foo4");
}
```

Now that you told me I can add extra argument I could just do

```java
String.Format(getFormatS(x), "foo1", "foo2", "foo3", "foo4")
```

**But** foos are generated by expensive functions and I prefer not calling them if I don't need to.

Comment: No, there is no way using String.Format, you can implement your own version of String.format if you really want it.

Comment: I am not sure what your goal is. What do you want to get when only `condition1` is true? OR what if only `condition2` is true?

Comment: it cannot happen, I didn't want to put the whole function in the question. Condition 1 is ``foo>10`` and condition 2 is ``foo >20``

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "it cannot happen"? (Or if it is answer to my comment or Victor's - in the future consider using `@nickOfPerson` like `%Pshemo` in your comments to point for who it is meant) If it was meant for me then do you mean that `condition1` and `condition2` can't have different values (since that was scenario I was asking about)?

Comment: @Pshemo as I said if condition2 is true, then condition1 will be true too

Comment: You referred only to second case from my first comment. So let me ask again: what if `condition1` is true while condition2 is false? Like when `foo=15` condition1 = `foo>10` so it is true but condition2 `foo>20` is false. What results do you expect for such case?

Comment: oh sorry I didn't understand. Actually in that case my function will return ``"%s, %s"`` but it uses the same condition as presented. I'll add the function to make the question more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can

```
if (condition1) {
     toFormatS = String.format(toFormatS, "foo", "foo2", "%s", "%s");
// that would make toFormatS equals to "foo, foo2 ; %s, %s"
}
if (condition2) {
     toFormatS = String.Format(toFormatS, "foo3", "foo4");
// that would make toFormatS equals to "foo, foo2 ; foo3, foo4"
}
```

and to many arguments in format are ignored.

Comment: @user15358848 I mena to replace the single line, and as I understop OP, in this case the format String has only two %s

Comment: And now lets pray that `foo` or `foo2` won't contain data which can be interpreted as placeholders like `%s` in `sos%sos`.

Comment: @user15358848, yeah, to many arguments was what I wanted to say, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want if you escape the last two % signs in the original format.

```
String toFormatS = "%s, %s ; %%s, %%s";
if (condition1) {
    toFormatS = String.format(toFormatS, "foo", "foo2");
    // that would make toFormatS equals to "foo, foo2 ; %s, %s"
}
        
if (condition2) {
    toFormatS = String.format(toFormatS, "foo3", "foo4");
    // that would make toFormatS equals to "foo, foo2 ; foo3, foo4"
}
```